# Should templates make non-Rvalue-reference constructors/assigns for move only parameters of different type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference

Let us say I have a move-only type.  We stop the default-provided constructors from existing, but Rvalue references introduce a new "flavor" we can use for the moving-versions of the signatures:

```
class CantCopyMe
{
private:
    CantCopyMe (CantCopyMe const & other) = delete;
    CantCopyMe & operator= (CantCopyMe const & other) = delete;

public:
    CantCopyMe (CantCopyMe && other) {
        /* ... */
    }

    CantCopyMe & operator= (CantCopyMe && other) {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

I recently thought you were *always* supposed to pass movable types by Rvalue reference.  Now it's looking like only very special cases need to do that...like these two.  Things had seemed to work most of the time if you put them everywhere, but I just found one case of the compiler not running the part of the code transferring ownership.

(It was a situation like passing a unique pointer held in a variable with `std::move` to something taking a `unique_ptr<foo> &&` parameter...but noticing the variable at the callsite hadn't been nulled.  Changing the parameter to `unique_ptr<foo>` fixed it and it was properly nulled, thus preventing a double-delete.  :-/  I haven't isolated why *this one* was bad when it seemed to work elsewhere, but a smoking gun is it worked the first time but not the subsequent calls.)

I'm sure there's a good reason for that, and many of you can saliently sum it up.  In the meantime I've started going around like a good [cargo-cult programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) removing the &&s.

But what if you're writing a templated class, where it looked like this?

```
template <class FooType>
class CantCopyMe
{
private:
    CantCopyMe (CantCopyMe const & other) = delete;
    CantCopyMe & operator= (CantCopyMe const & other) = delete;

public:
    template<class OtherFooType>
    CantCopyMe (CantCopyMe<OtherFooType> && other) {
        /* ... */
    }

    template<class OtherFooType>
    CantCopyMe & operator= (CantCopyMe<OtherFooType> && other) {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Is that bad practice for some reason, and you should break out separately when OtherFooType and FooType aren't the same... then it just passes by value?

```
template <class FooType>
class CantCopyMe
{
private:
    CantCopyMe (CantCopyMe const & other) = delete;
    CantCopyMe & operator= (CantCopyMe const & other) = delete;

public:
    CantCopyMe (CantCopyMe && other) {
        /* ... */
    }

    CantCopyMe & operator= (CantCopyMe && other) {
        /* ... */
    }

    template<class OtherFooType>
    CantCopyMe (CantCopyMe<OtherFooType> other) {
        /* ... */
    }

    template<class OtherFooType>
    CantCopyMe & operator= (CantCopyMe<OtherFooType> other) {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Comment: *"Changing the parameter to unique_ptr<foo> fixed it and it was properly nulled"* Sounds like the function taking the rvalue ref didn't actually move? Other than that, IMHO it's a bit vague.

Comment: @DyP *That* part's vague, but it's not the question... insight is welcome, of course, but not required.

Comment: Well you said yourself the whole issue is or might be cargo-cult programming. There's indeed a "school of thought" that suggests taking sink arguments by value, as it's better than just to have a `const&` version and less work than definiting `&&` and `const&` overloads for every combination of parameters. That said, if you *do* provide both, you might move only once where the by-value version might have to move twice. If moving is expensive, that might be preferable.

Comment: Oh, I just remembered: a constructor template is never considered a move constructor, and an operator template is never considered a move-assignment op.

Comment: @DyP so what exactly happens if you have a perfectly forwarded constructor template and you pass it an r-val?

Comment: @aaronman If there's an implicitly-declared move ctor, this implicitly-declared ctor might be called (e.g. if both rank as Exact Match, the implicitly-declared ctor is not a template specialization). If the constructor template specialization matches better or if there's no implicitly-declared move ctor, the constructor template specialization will be called. It won't be "move construction" I think, but "ordinary construction"; this might be relevant for `is_move_constructible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a simple answer for a possibly unexpected reason:

A copy-/move constructor or assignment-operator is *never* a template (specialization). E.g. [class.copy]/2

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

Also, footnote 122 says:

> Because a template assignment operator or an assignment operator taking an rvalue reference parameter is never a copy assignment operator, the presence of such an assignment operator does not suppress the implicit declaration of a copy assignment operator. Such assignment operators participate in overload resolution with other assignment operators, including copy assignment operators, and, if selected, will be used to assign an object.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct X
{
    X() {}

    template<class U>
    X(X<U>&&)
    {
        std::cout << "template \"move\" ctor\n";
    }

    template<class U>
    X& operator= (X<U>&&)
    {
        std::cout << "template \"move\" assignment-op\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X<int> x;                     // no output
    X<int> y(x);                  // no output
    y = std::move(x);             // no output
    X<double> z( std::move(x) );  // output
    y = std::move(z);             // output
}
```

In this example, the implicitly-declared move constructor and move assignment-operator are used.

---

Therefore, if you don't declare a non-template move ctor and move assignment-operator, they might be declared implicitly. They're not declared implicitly e.g. for the move assignment-op, if you have a user-declared dtor; for details see [class.copy]/11 and [class.copy]/20.

Example: Adding a dtor to the example above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct X
{
    X() {}
    ~X() {}

    template<class U>
    X(X<U>&&)
    {
        std::cout << "template \"move\" ctor\n";
    }

    template<class U>
    X& operator= (X<U>&&)
    {
        std::cout << "template \"move\" assignment-op\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X<int> x;                     // no output
    X<int> y(x);                  // no output
    y = std::move(x);             // output
    X<double> z( std::move(x) );  // output
    y = std::move(z);             // output
}
```

Here, the first move-assignment `y = std::move(x);` calls a specialization of the assignment-operator template, because there's no implicitly declared move assignment-operator.

Comment: Well, that explains that--thanks!  (It did get me suspicious enough to ask.)  I still don't fully understand when I should be using && and not in parameters.  You mentioned conflicting schools of thought; is there a good answer for *"should movable types passed as parameters be declared as R-value reference or not?"* which says something besides *"no, they shouldn't?"* (that's what I've found)

Comment: @HostileFork Well as I said - you can get more efficient code if you use rvalue-refs as parameter types (as only one move happens semantically). The couplings will be different from the pass-by-value case, as the decision between copying and moving (and which to allow) now are made by the function signature, not the type itself.